# org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)

Tags: grails

This error has been plaguing me for 6 months, and dont know how to solve it.

The first problem is the stack trace doesnt give any hints as to what line, query or controller is causing the issue.  The error happens in PageFragmentCachingFilter.java

I do a couple of concurrent things, I update a counter in the DB each time a specific function is called.  If two people execute this at exactly the same time, there could be locking issue.

My controller does 3 things:

1. reads a row from the grails DB of a domain object called Query (using Query.get(id))
2. calls a service to pull a bunch of data from an external db. This takes several minutes
3. increments a value in the row which was read from the db.
4. saves the row with (failOnError: false)

The failOnError = false was an attempt to make the problem go away, by ignoring an update error, but it didnt work - still exception occurs.

The problems is:

1. I dont know if this is the problem. or how to find where the problem is actually occurring.
2. I dont know why setting failOnError: false did not fix it.
3. i dont know how to turn the pessimistic lock into a real lock which makes you wait (see below attempts at this)
4. I dont know at what point the locking is occurring, so it only locks for the minimum amount of time.

I can reproduce the issue by calling the controller from two different browser windows at the same time.

=== update 1 ===
I tried putting steps 3 and 4 in a service, on the understanding that services start and end transactions automatically. This did not solve the problem, but does throw the same exeption on the line which calls this new service to update a a counter, so this at least points to the issue.

Lets say there is a domain object report which looks like this:

```
class Query {
  String sql
  String name
  int counter
}
```

The steps are now:

1. Read the required Query instance from the grails DB, e.g. Query.get(1)
2. Call a service which takes a long time, passing in the sql value.
3. call a service, passing the query instance object.  This service increments counter, then calls save. (see below code)

Two different people do the above steps at the same time on the same query object.

```
@Transactional
class aService {

    def count(Query query) {
        query.counter++
        query.save();
    }
```

The above, even though its transactional, fails with the same error.

I assume that i need to do something like re-read the instance object again.

==== update 2 =====

tried changing the service to do this:

```
def count(Query query) {
    Query q2 = Query.get(query.id)
    q2.counter++
    q2.save();
}
```

get same error when two people try to do this a the same time.  Doesnt work.

=== update 3 ====

looked for a way to do "select for update", so that it would lock the row, update it, release.  This MUST be multi-user safe.

Tried this:

```
def count(Query query) {
    Query q2 = Query.get(query.id)
    q2.lock()
    q2.counter++
    q2.save();
}
```

Guess what?  Same error, but this time throws it on the lock line.  How can doing a fresh select for update cause a staleObjectStateException?

=== update 4 ====

Tried this:

```
def count(Query query) {
    Query q2 = Query.lock(query.id)
    q2.counter++
    q2.save();
}
```

Guess what?  Same error.  Seems there is no way to update a counter used by 2 or more people.  Also, I can reproduce 100% of the time, which is very odd as this error should only occur very infrequent due to the speed of this simple update.  Something is very wrong.

=== update 5 ========

Getting more desperate.  Tried the following:

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.*
class aService {
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
def count(Query query) {
    Query q2 = Query.lock(query.id)
    q2.counter++
    q2.save(flush:true);
}
```

Same error on the lock row. It seems its just not possible in grails to do the equivalent of

```
update query set counter = counter + 1 where id = y
```

or even

```
select * from query where id = 1 for update
update query set counter = counter + 1 where id = 1
commit
```

=== update 6 ====

Interestingly, the read which happens in step 1 uses get. I tried changing this to read(id), in the hopes that this might help.  Interestingly, if I read the instance using read, the app fails on this line every time, even with 1 user:

```
    Query q2 = Query.lock(query.id)
```

With the error:

```
 attempted to lock a deleted instance
```

WTH?  firstly, I have not deleted any instances, secondly, I have attempted to lock a nice NEW read, thirdly, I didnt edit or change the original read object.

Comment: updating a counter like this is rather resource heavy (given, that this is no trivialized example).  `update t set counter=counter+1 where id=:id` directly is preferrable.

Comment: what grails and hibernate versions are you using?  what is the used database?  what are your cache settings?

Comment: Grails 2.3.11. mysql 5.6.  How do I find out my cache settings?

Comment: update query set counter=counter+1 where id=:id IS WHAT I WANT TO DO!  I cant find any way to do that with gails + hibernate.

Comment: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeUpdate.html